# Is P90NF03L 3.3V logic level MOSFET?

Tags: voltage, mosfet, digital-logic, logic-level

So I want to control my 12V (up to 10A) load through a 3.3V logic level MOSFET. I have purchased the [P90NF03L MOSFET](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stp90nf03l.pdf) but I don't trust my datasheet reading skills so could someone please confirm that this is indeed 3.3V logic level MOSFET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In datasheets of most transistors, it is not explicitly mentioned whether they are logic level MOSFETs or not. The quickest way to tell is by looking at the Rds(on) section in the datasheet.

[image: Parameters P90NF03L]

Notice that Rds(on) for 5V is mentioned. This is an indication that it is a logic level MOSFET. Judging from the transfer characteristics curve in the datasheet, you should be able to use it easily for your load at a Vgs of 3.3V.

[image: Transfer characteristics curve]

Comment: Ok. Someone had said that if Vgs(th) is less than 3.3V then it is logic level at 3.3V. I can see from table 3 that Vgs(th) for this MOSFET is max 2.5V. But I needed to be sure. Thanks.

Comment: You typically need about 0.5V higher than Vgs(th) for reliable operation and reasonable conduction losses.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this transconductance graph shows that with a Gate Source Voltage of 3V and 10A through it, there is a worst case of about 1V drop across.
[image: Transconductance of MOSFET]

With figure 6, you see at your operating conditions (close as Vgs is 10V in the Graph), the on resistance is 10V/25A=0.4Ohm at 3V.
[image: RDS graph]

Answer (score 1):

According to Figure 3 it is usable as low as 2.5V and 3.0V looks OK, if you don't need to drive very high current.

Comment: I'm expecting something up to 10Amps

Comment: Should be OK, but might dissipate as much as 10 watts, so it will need a heat sink.